# ImportError: No module named os

Tags: python, linux, unix, system-administration

When I am executing any command which has "import os " is showing below error :

No module named os

For example :

```
$ sudo -iCould not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
'import site' failed; use -v for traceback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/tss/bin/scbtools.py", line 30, in <module>
    import sys, os, re
ImportError: No module named os`
```

Comment: what's this bogus command line: `sudo -iCould not find platform independent libraries <prefix>` ??? you may have lost your `PYTHONPATH` and `PYTHONHOME` variables in the `sudo` process.

Comment: Command is "sudo -i" only rest was error.

Can you please help me,how to get the PYTHONHOME in sudo process.

Comment: okay but you'd need to [edit] your question. Right now it's unclear.

Comment: So the python script is one that's run when someone logs in? Or just when root logs in?  In either case, `sudo -i` clears out most of the environment, `sudo -s` inherits a lot more of it, and  you can edit your sudoers file to change what environment is kept - `man sudoers` for more information

Comment: you could try to `unset PYTHONHOME`

Comment: I'm tryin from root.

Eg:
$ambari-agent start
Verifying Python version compatibility...
Using python  /usr/bin/python2.6
Starting ambari-agent
ERROR: ambari-agent start failed.
====================
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
'import site' failed; use -v for traceback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ambari_agent/AmbariAgent.py", line 21, in <module>
    import os
ImportError: No module named os

Comment: Whenever python script is running I am getting the same error.

import sys, os, re
ImportError: No module named os

Comment: The `ambari-agent start` command in that comment is not in the question. Is this a hosted web service somewhere?